# VBA in Excel: Code to change a filename based on information entered into a userform?

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

I am creating an Excel workbook, which is coded to work as follows:

1) User is guided through a series of user forms, entering information for specific situation

2) When user clicks final command button (in last userform), information is populated in one of 5 tabs of the workbook.

3) User reviews information populated, and then clicks a button which populates a different tab in the same workbook.  The information populated is used to generate a text file, which is then saved to a specific location in the directory.

4) The file is picked up during a sweep, and used to create a task in an ancillary application.

My question is: Is there a way to save the text file with a specific name, based on information in one of the cells of the tab used to create the text file?

I apologize if this is not thorough or well-written.  I am relatively new to VBA.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after, or should maybe get you started. Create a test workbook somewhere (e.g. Desktop or My Documents). Put some text in `cell A1`. Try the following code:

```
Sub saveTxtFileWithCell()
    Dim myDir      As String
    Dim myFilename As String

    myDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
    myFilename = myDir + "\" + Range("A1") + " " + Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") + ".txt"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=myFilename, _
        FileFormat:=xlText, _
        CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

This will save a .txt file with the name of the contents from cell A1 with today's date. You should be able to adapt this code such that rather than utilizing `cell A1` you use the contents saved in the userform.